# tbb::parallel_for with preserved order

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb, thread-local-storage

I have a single loop which I want to parallelize. The loop implies doing the following:

```
std::vector<int> input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
std::vector<int> output;
for(size_t i(0); i < input.size(); ++i)
{
    output.emplace_back(input[i] * 2);
}
```

However, I would like to preserve the order in the output. I tried to use *tbb::enumerable_thread_specific* to do that:

```
tbb::enumerable_thread_specific<std::vector<int>> threadData;
tbb::parallel_for(size_t{0}, input.size(), [&](size_t i)
{
    auto& local = threadData.local();
    local.emplace_back(2 * input[i]);
});

for (const auto& local : threadData)
{
    output.insert(output.begin() + output.size(), local.begin(), local.end());
}
```

However, the order is not preserved. I also tried to specify the partitioner:

```
tbb::static_partitioner()
```

but it didn't help as well.

What is the correct way to parallelize a for loop while preserving the order in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a task in parallel while preserving a given order is generally hard (and not always possible) since it often means some things should be done sequentially.

Here you can easily solve this thanks to direct indexing:

```cpp
std::vector<int> input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
std::vector<int> output(input.size());

tbb::parallel_for(size_t{0}, input.size(), [&](size_t i)
{
    output[i] = input[i] * 2;
}
```

Keep in mind that resizing vectors (and more generally working on dynamically sized data) in a parallel context is often a bad idea.